# Completeness of Gleason metric for uniform algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

> Question: Suppose $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space, $\mathcal{A}$ be a [uniform algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_algebra) on $X$, and $B(\cal{A})$ denotes the open unit ball of $\cal{A}$. For $x,y\in X$, define $$d(x,y):= \sup_{f\in B(\cal{A})} \big|\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{1-\overline{f(x)}f(y)}\big|.$$ Prove $d$ is a complete metric on $X$.(Note that the topology induced by $d$ may different with original one)

The term in supreme is actually the pseudo-Poincare distence of $f(x)$ and $f(y)$, it follows that $d$ is a metric by definition. For completeness, Herbert S. Bear's book ,*letures on Gleason part*, wrote: because $X$ homemorphic to the maximal ideal space of $C(X)$, so(?)there is subsequence $\{x_{n_k}\}$ $w^*$-converges to some $x$. Then we can prove $d(x_n,x)\to 0$ by some $\epsilon-\delta$ arguments. But I was confused why such subsequence exists? Of course, in general, compact $\neq$ sequential compact!

Here is the picture of that book. Its notation may different, but the meaning is the same as above.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the proof in this book is not accurate.  Now I‘ll be a tinker.

**Proof of the completeness**: Let $\{x_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $(X,d)$. Then for each fixed $f\in \cal{A}$,$\{f(x_n)\}\subseteq \mathbb{D}$ is a Cauchy sequence in [Poincaré disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_disk_model). Because Poincaré disk is complete, $f(x_n)\to \delta(f)\in \mathbb{D}$. Let $\delta_{x_n}$ denotes the evaluation functional at $x_n$. $\mathcal{M}_\mathcal{A}$ denotes the maximal ideal space of $\mathcal{A}$. Above shows $\delta_{x_n}$ $w^*$-converges to $\delta \in \mathcal{M}_{\mathcal{A}}$.

The crucial point is note that the embedding $X \hookrightarrow \mathcal{M_A}$ is continuous, $X$ is compact and $\cal{M_A}$ is Hausdorff. So X is closed in $\cal{M_A}$, and $\delta=\delta_x \in X$. Standard $\epsilon-\delta$ arguments shows $x_n\to x$ in $(X,d)$.